# ORDER BY not working inside JOIN SELECT

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables: `ticket` and `ticket_message`.

I want to select all tickets, that were not answered by our support team. This means last message, left in ticket, will have type `client`.

I trying code like this:

```sql
SELECT `ticket`.*,`message`.*
FROM `ticket` 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM `ticket_message` ORDER BY `timeCreated` DESC) AS `message` ON `message`.`ticketId` = `ticket`.`id`
GROUP BY `ticket`.`id`
HAVING `message`.`type` = 'client'
```

The thing is, that this code works perfectly on my dev server with MySQL 5.5.42, but messages does not sort in subquery on production server with MySQL 5.7.9

Here is `EXPLAIN` results:

**for 5.5.42:**

```
id  select_type  table type      possible_keys  key   key_len  ref   rows  Extra
1   PRIMARY      ticket          ALL            NULL  NULL     NULL  NULL  38  
1   PRIMARY      <derived2>      ALL            NULL  NULL     NULL  NULL  130 
2   DERIVED      ticket_message  ALL            NULL  NULL     NULL  NULL  127 Using filesort
```

**for 5.7.9:**

```
id  select_type  table           partitions  type   possible_keys                        key                    key_len  ref        rows    filtered  Extra
1   SIMPLE       ticket          NULL        index  PRIMARY,ticket_ibfk_1,ticket_ibfk_2  PRIMARY                4        NULL       38      100.00    NULL
1   SIMPLE       ticket_message  NULL        ref    ticket_message_ibfk_1                ticket_message_ibfk_1  5        ticket.id  3       100.00    NULL
```

Comment: Why don't you just `LEFT JOIN ticket_message`?  What *results* are you trying to get?  Also, what do you expect the `ORDER BY timeCreated` to do?

Comment: Also for your query, this `ORDER BY \`timeCreated\` DESC` is not needed at all, actually it will increase the planning.

Comment: There's no point in sorting inside the join for this query.  Just sort on the result after the join.

Comment: Does not sort by what, timecreated or ticketid?

Comment: This kind of problem is (correctly) answered several times daily. It even has its own chapter in the manual.

Comment: @RocketHazmat ORDER BY `timeCreated` DESC` need to select only last messages

Comment: @Shadow It does not sort by timeCreated in join subquery, but I really need to select only last messages of every ticket

Comment: @ArtemB.: What do you mean by "last messages"?  Without a `WHERE` or `LIMIT` clause, your subquery will return *every* row from `ticket_message`.  Can you show us an example of the *result* you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

There's no guarantee that the ordering inside a subquery will be preserved. And in this case you can just use a join rather than a subquery.

Does this work?

```
SELECT `ticket`.*,`ticket_message`.* FROM `ticket` 
LEFT JOIN  `ticket_message`  ON `ticket_message`.`ticketId` = `ticket`.`id` 
GROUP BY `ticket`.`id` ORDER BY `ticket_message`.`timeCreated` DESC
```

I'm not sure what  you want to achieve, but you may want to put `ticket_message`.`timeCreated` into the group by or you may get unexpected results.

Note on using "Group By"

It is easy to get caught out using Group By and there are rules that should be followed

Fields you are selecting should appear in the "Group By" clause. If they are not in the group by clause they should have an aggregate function applied.

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-99/rules-for-grouping-columns/

Comment: From the explains it is clear that v5.7 optimised away the subquery, since there is not derived table there, while 5.5 executed the query as it was written. This seems to be the reason for any difference in sorting.

Comment: +1 for the opening remark. -2 for what using a GROUP BY clause in the absence of any aggregating functions.

Comment: @Shadow Yeah. Do you know any way to get rid of this optimization?

Comment: @ArtemB. Downgrade your mysql back to v5.6 at least. v5.7's main improvement is subquery optimization. Do the order by in the outer query.

Comment: @Strawberry I know, my final sentence was alluding to this problem with the original query.